# Fluid simulation tutorial in javascript, values never initialized?

Tags: javascript, math, physics, fluid-dynamics

I am looking at [this](https://github.com/matthias-research/pages/blob/master/tenMinutePhysics/18-flip.html#L528) snippet in a fluid simulation tutorial.

I have searched for where those values are initialised and it seems they are never written to? There is a line that initialises the array `this.s`.

`this.s = new Float32Array(this.fNumCells);`

However, past that, I fail to see a single write into it. There's multiple reads throughout the code.

e.g.:

```js
var s = this.s[center];
var sx0 = this.s[left];
var sx1 = this.s[right];
var sy0 = this.s[bottom];
var sy1 = this.s[top];
```

Am I missing something? I am not that familiar with javascript but under the assumption that declaring an array with a known size defaults initialises its values to 0, my current reading of the code suggests this snippet is not doing anything, since s would always be 0 and it would be skipped?

But when I run it in the browser and use a `console.log` statement to inspect s, it does have values I see `s = 3, 4 etc...`

How does it have any values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is updated, [here](https://github.com/matthias-research/pages/blob/master/tenMinutePhysics/18-flip.html#L746):

`f.s[i*n + j] = s`